# Creating query for set of polygons which would select adjacent polygons for which combined area is greater than number?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, area, spatial-query

I have a set of parcels, represented as polygons shapefiles and I need to build a query, to select all the polygons, which are adjacent, with the sum of the areas of 2 polygons,greater than 1000 acres.

Is this even possible to query in arcmap/pro, or it requires scripting?

Google was so not so keen in providing an answer to such a complex question. I know how to do simple queries in Arcmap, and calculate areas and joining adjacent polygons, but this is a little bit more than what I know.

I could do it manually, but this is going to be a recursive task, so need some automation.

Comment: As for any automation task start by listing the precise manual steps that you perform.

Comment: I am interested if this can be done by query(query is enough automated for me), no model needed.

Comment: I would try Select By Attribute in combination with Select By Location.

Comment: Not sure about query, but spatial join one to many (on itself) should give you enough info, providing areas were present in table

Comment: Could you be more detailed FelixIP. How do I interpret the resulting attribute table of that join?

Comment: Are you open to a scripted solution?  It would be easiest to accomplish this with a python script (or a model if you don't have any scripting knowledge).

Comment: jbalk@ more open to a model, because I lack in scripting. Although in the meantime I found the solution and I will be posting it shortly, I am still very interested to see your approach.